# A two-method program for running background jobs

Tags: ruby, child-process, unix

*Edit: since originally posting this I have: realized that it won't run from irb/pry, and refactored to remove some `sleep` calls. I've also separated the sections into different code blocks.*

I wanted to make a program for running background jobs (ruby scripts).

The goal was to continuously run a background script on an interval of N seconds until a kill command was issued.

See below for my implementation. Note that **this cannot be pasted into irb or pry, it will cause an orphan process. Run it from a script instead**. Why is this the case? I don't know. Do you?

The program prints out the process name. In the case of an orphaned process, run `ps aux` with the process name and `kill -9` on each PID shown.

**Stdlib depencies and basic OOP setup**

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'tempfile'
class Backgrounder
  attr_accessor :process_name, :interval, :script_content
  def initialize(options={})
    @interval, @script_content = options.values_at(:interval, :script_content)
    raise ArgumentError unless [interval, script_content].all?
  end
end
```

**"begin" command** - saves the script to a tempfile, starts a subshell running IRB,
loads the script into IRB, and saves the process identifier.

```
class Backgrounder
    def begin
        tempfile_name = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        tempfile = Tempfile.new(tempfile_name)
        tempfile_path = tempfile.path
        tempfile_content = <<-RUBY
            $0 = "#{tempfile_name}" # changes the name of the program
            while true
              #{self.script_content}
              sleep #{self.interval.to_f / 1000}
            end
        RUBY
        tempfile.write(tempfile_content)
        tempfile.close # saves the write
        require 'byebug'
        cmd = <<-SH
            echo "load '#{tempfile_path}'" | irb
        SH
        cmd_pid = spawn(cmd, pgroup: true) # runs the tempfile in IRB
        self.process_name = tempfile_name # used later to kill the process
        Process.detach(cmd_pid) # prevents the process from blocking the current script
      end
    end
```

**"kill" command** - loops twice for good measure
because orphan processes are really annoying. it actully makes a difference though.
My test program (shown later) didnt work otherwise. `kill -9` is called twice per
iteration because there are actually two processes for each process_name. 
The first is the headless irb console, and the second is the loaded file.

```
class Backgrounder
    def kill
        2.times {
            puts "--------\Trying to kill process named: #{self.process_name}\n----------"
            pid1 = `ps aux | grep #{self.process_name} | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`.chomp
            `kill -9 #{pid1}`
            pid2 = `ps aux | grep #{self.process_name} | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'`.chomp
            `kill -9 #{pid2}`
        }
    end
end
```

**Usage example / test code** - start and stop 2 background processes.

```
# Initialize Backgrounder object with script and interval
process1 = Backgrounder.new(
  interval: 2000, script_content: "system('chromium-browser http://google.com')"
)
process2 = Backgrounder.new(
  interval: 2000, script_content: "system('chromium-browser http://yahoo.com')"
)

# start processes, opens chrome tabs once every two seconds
[process1, process2].each(&:begin)

 # some sleep time is required between starting & stopping a process
sleep 2

# stop the processes
[process1, process2].each(&:kill)
```

Comment: I'm confused. How is this different from looping `system("curl &"); sleep 1` or similar indefinitely?

Comment: @BarryCarter this enables running many loops simultaneously, and all of them are non-blocking. I.e. theres no reason to have the main thread `sleep`.